# Routed Direction using GooglemapforAsp.net control

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to research the routed direction using google maps for asp.net control. Here is my Code.

```
GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.APIKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleAPIKey"];         
GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.Width = "1100px"; 
GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.Height = "600px";       
GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.ZoomLevel = 10;        
GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.CenterPoint = new GooglePoint("1", 1.352083, 103.819836);

GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.ShowTraffic = true;         
int count=0;
bool flag = false;   
GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.Points.Clear();
foreach (var gitem in tblG)
{          
    foreach (var item in tblDT)
    {
        if (item.Latitude==gitem.Latitude && item.Longitude==gitem.Longitude && flag!=true)
        {
            count += 1;
            GooglePoint GP1 = new GooglePoint();
            GP1.ID = "GP" + count.ToString();                       
            GP1.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(gitem.Latitude);//latitude;
            GP1.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(gitem.Longitude);
            GP1.InfoHTML = " Name:<b>" + Name + "</b></br>Point:<b>" + "GP" + count.ToString() + "</b></br>Time:<b>" + gitem.CDate.ToString() + "</b></br>";//stime;
            GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.Points.Add(GP1);
            string address = gitem.Latitude + "," + gitem.Longitude;
            GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.Directions.Addresses.Add(address);

            flag = true;
        }  
    }
    flag = false;               
}
```

I want it as Routed Direction is only between start and End point.

But I got result look like driving Direction. I don't want to get that result. How to fix that problem?

Comment: What is the difference between "Routed Direction" and "Driving Direction"?

Comment: I know Driving Direction mean Giving instruction How to drive the way.